# Which martial arts exercise helps to reduce weight?

Tags: weight

I am almost 100 Kg or 220 lbs. My height is 5 ft 9 inches. I do everyday gymimg for almost 70-80 mins. Can anyone suggest me some videos or links which combines both weight loss along with getting good at martial arts ?

Comment: Do you want to actually go to a martial arts school to train, or do you mean that you want to add something to your gym experience in solo? Like maybe your gym has an aerobics room that lets you do stuff, and you see yourself learning some martial arts workout routines from video and doing them by yourself at your gym?

Comment: I would like to add something in my Gym workout . I do punch & throw kicks to punching Bags move around like Boxers which I feel sheds more calories compared to a Cardio exercise on a Tread Mill or Elliptical . That's the reason I was looking for any other .

Comment: If you add some kicking to your moving "around like boxers" you'll burn more calories.  Low turning kicks are the easiest technique to deliver vaguely passably.  But you won't get *good* at martial arts unless you join a dedicated martial arts class and take the time to learn and understand the technique; no matter what art you pick, not all *that* practice will be cardio intensive.  Kyokushin big-mitt training is a great cardio workout too, but you'd need a partner to hold the mitt and would be best off joining a dojo for that.

Comment: Might want to migrate to sports/health.  Exercise reduces weight. There is no magic exercise.  Your weight is the calories you take in minus the calories you burn in activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weight loss is highly individualistic. What works for some doesn't work for others, and vice-versa.

Consistency is the most important thing when it comes to exercise and health in general. So if you can find something you really enjoy doing, it makes it much more likely you'll continue doing it day after day.

Unlike some others here, I'm not going to suggest that martial arts practice is unsuitable for weight loss, because it can be used for exactly that purpose. And for some people, martial arts is more than just exercise. It becomes recreational, interesting, and continuously challenging.

That satisfies the main requirement that I mentioned above: Consistency. If it's something you enjoy doing, you'll keep doing it.

In general, weight loss is a combination of exercise and diet. Everyone knows that. That's no secret. And what most people also realize is that you need both in order to lose weight reliably.

Yes, you can just exercise alone or just diet alone and not both together, but eventually most people with that approach find that their weight loss plateaus. They might lose a ton of weight at first, and then it gradually becomes less and less. At some point they just stop losing weight altogether. When weight loss stops, it can be frustrating enough to go back to eating more and not exercising, and then the weight comes back really fast.

So the key thing to take from this is that exercise and diet must both be controlled if weight loss is to happen reliably. Both have their own issues and require some planning, and trial and error.

As for diet, there are plenty of approaches. It can be pretty overwhelming trying to choose one that works for you. So I won't say anything about any particular diet. I'll just say that successful dieters generally eat 3 meals a day, don't skip meals, don't starve themselves, limit their portion sizes, and cut out junk food, colas, and candy.

They also enjoy their diet. It shouldn't be something that requires tremendous willpower. If eating salads is your idea of torture, then don't do diets where salads are the main course.

If you want to go above and beyond that, start counting calories and limit yourself to some number of calories per day. There are calculators online for figuring out exactly how many calories you should eat in order to lose weight. But for most people, simply controlling portion sizes and not eating crap will suffice. The easier it is to follow, the less likely you'll stop doing it.

Okay, that brings me to exercise. Exercise can be aerobic or anaerobic. It can be all cardio and no resistance. It can be all resistance (strength) and no cardio. It can be sporadic (work and rest cycles). Or it can be continuous. And it can be any combination of these, or somewhere in between.

Which exercise is best for weight loss?

The answer is that it depends on a number of things. First and foremost is how much time you have in your schedule to workout. If you have just 30 minutes a day to workout, or maybe an hour every other day, then that says you probably need to think about getting the most calories burned per minute. For that, you'll want to do something akin to High Intensity Interval Training.

Then again, another factor is how fast you want to burn your fat. If you're okay with losing just a small amount of weight per month, then you might be able to accomplish that by just sticking with a lower intensity workout, such as strength training (weightlifting) or riding an exercise bike at a rate that doesn't cause much of a sweat.

You can try whatever you like first. Such as martial arts practice. So long as you're continuing to lose weight over time at the rate you want, you're fine. Increase your intensity if you see yourself plateauing or even gaining weight over time. Or change your exercise completely. It involves some trial and error.

Martial arts practice actually does fit this description pretty well. You can adapt it to a high intensity interval workout very easily. Or it can be light and continuous. This includes exercises like punching and kicking to a bag or even to the air.

Jumping rope is something you can take right out of boxing training, and there are videos on how boxers jump rope. There are grappling exercises as well that can be done, such as shrimping, weighted sled, tire rolling, walking on all fours across the floor, climbing rope, etc.

Take a look at the warm-up exercises that Gracie Jiujitsu or MMA gyms do and repeat the ones you find interesting.

There are also kata / forms. Karate, Taekwondo, and Kung-Fu have them. You can maybe learn one from video and repeat, repeat, repeat.

The good thing about forms is that after you repeat one maybe 100 times, it will be committed to memory. You won't have to think much about what you're doing. At that point, you're just trying to go as fast as you can and repeat it as many times as you can in a row before you collapse. It becomes a nice, compact workout program you can whip out whenever and wherever you are.

Movements in forms exercise a lot of muscles that are often neglected in traditional exercise programs. It can be intense at first. You might find your legs shaking after doing them. And over time you can increase the level of difficulty by lowering and elongating your stance and making your strikes pop faster and harder.

Choosing a form to start with is tricky if you haven't done them before. I recommend starting with a basic form from karate or taekwondo. Those forms don't have much variation and won't exercise the whole body, but they still give you something. If you learn multiple forms, you'll probably get more of a complete body workout.

Some of the more advanced forms have you moving in weird ways that are physically challenging. And if you really want a challenge, look at traditional or contemporary Wushu Kung-Fu forms. I find kung-fu forms in general to involve a lot more variation of movement than karate or taekwondo forms do.

You don't need forms, though. Like I mentioned before, you can just take the drills straight from boxing, karate, muay thai, BJJ, MMA, and wrestling. Combine the drills together to make a workout. You can absolutely work yourself out that way. And you can do it in as little as 10 minutes a day in addition to your normal gym workout.

There are tons of videos online for this purpose. Here are some I found just with a quick search of Youtube. I've selected them to cover a broad range of martial arts styles from grappling to pure striking, eastern and western:

  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXjP50SOwK4
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRUtpYQ0c6E
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4luaFHs7O4
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suvM7sJo-6w
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2b3tQIZaUcw
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aO3uaGOu2Oo
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpGGMkphci8
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTwPEfMUauw
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ujly7l3-xUM

That's not by any means a complete list. There are thousands of videos just like these, and they all have some things that you might find interesting enough to take and use.

And below are some "forms" videos that I thought you might want to look at. These are arguably some of the most well known forms from karate, traditional and contemporary / northern and southern kung-fu, and taekwondo. I chose them based on my personal experience in these martial arts.

Some are basic, some are advanced. The videos are sometimes grainy, out of focus, or may only cover one viewing angle. And these particular demonstrations aren't necessarily ones that I think are good to learn from. They just showed up on a simple search, that's all, and they at least show the form reasonably well.

The important thing is to get the name of the form and look up other versions online to correct yourself, if you want to learn them. Since they're very popular and widely practiced forms, you should have no problem finding other videos and articles that discuss them:

  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOEgRrWZh48
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2da_YijN9U
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fict-rt_a1I
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rnar_APMgI
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=koOaztyceUs
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFKWfAlgGKw
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ip4gKICJD6c
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVz-Wkm3pfw
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jJuTkz0psY
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FomUPyqf-qY

One final thought about using martial arts as a form of exercise...

A lot of people here will probably cringe at the thought of someone learning to do martial arts movement from video without proper, in-person instruction. They'll point out that without an instructor to correct your movement in person, you're going to learn the wrong movement, and you're going to drill that into your muscle memory. If you were then to go on to learn martial arts for real at a school, your instructor will have to work a lot harder to correct you, because all of the flaws you learned over time have to be un-done. It's much easier undoing flaws before you drill them in to your muscle memory, before it becomes a bad habit.

That is something to think about, if you ever intend to go into martial arts "for real", rather than just learning it as a form of exercise.

This idea applies to any form of exercise as well, by the way. If you learn how to do weightlifting from videos or from a book, rather than getting with a personal trainer who can correct your form in person, there's a good chance you're going to learn it incorrectly, or at least sub-optimally.

In weightlifting, if you have bad form, it can cause serious injuries over time. In martial arts, that's less of a concern, since you're not putting huge loads on your body - with the exception of doing punching bag work, where you can cause injury over time with the wrong form.

So these are things to think about. If you're uncertain after watching videos, it might be time to head to a martial arts school and enroll in some classes for however long, until you feel confident that you've learned the correct movement.

And the biggest thing to keep in mind: If you feel like something is causing pain, stop immediately. Pain is usually your body's way of saying you're doing it wrong, or you're not ready for this movement.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a ton @Steve Weigand ...the article is brief and helpful indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that has cardio as part of it should suffice.  This is a one that I have heard a lot about https://www.taebo.com/ there are forms of Cardio kickboxing that I have participated in as well which is basically kicks/punches etc... in a fluid continuous motion to music to get the heartbeat up for the duration of exercising.

Answer (score 1):

Martial arts are the wrong vehicle for weight lose.

First, muscle weights more than fat so hard martial art training will make you gain weight as you build muscle. Those muscles will be specialised in doing the right thing for the specific art you train in. If you want broad spectrum, you have to cross-train. Second, your body is super lazy and the amount of energy you have to spend to do the same set of moves will diminish over time. This is why variety is important in weight lose exercises. Thirdly, martial arts do nothing about your calorific intake but put more pressure on you to eat more.

100kg for 175cm tells us nothing about your fat percentage or your waste to height ratio. The less said about the aberration that is BMI, the best. Furthermore, nothing is said about what type of body you wish you had: slim free-climber one or body builder one! Clearly, the training will be different.

Comment: Thanks @Sardathrion ....I would like to add something in my Gym workout . I do punch & throw kicks to punching Bags move around like Boxers, jump with spinning kicks which I feel sheds more calories compared to a constant Cardio exercise on a Tread Mill or Elliptical as it makes me much more exhausted. Do you think it is good for calorie loss as it also gives a lot of flexibility .

Comment: If you want cardio, train that. If you want flexibility, train that. If you want calorie burn, train that. If you want to learn a martial art, train that. *They are all separate things.* To be fair, those things all help each other but then again, so does ballet.